# Papers/books with theoretical data on anharmonic oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, anharmonic-oscillators

I am trying to solve an-harmonic oscillator (with $x^4$ terms) and need theoretical data to compare with my numerical data. I have searched research papers on anharmonic oscillators and few spectroscopy books like Banwell's.

Can anyone recommend books or papers with theoretical data on an-harmonic oscillators?

Comment: I do not believe that the anharmonic oscillator van be solved analytically

Comment: The best that you could do is compare to a perturbations theory resilt.

Comment: What's "theoretical data"?

Comment: some data using which I can verify that what I have done is correct.

Comment: It is good idea to use several different methods and compare results. You can get decent estimates using variational methods and perturbation theory.

Comment: It will be nice if I can compare my result with data workout by someone else it will same my time and effort.